# Author Page - List of categories plus number of posts in that category

Tags: categories, author

On my author page I currently have a list of categories the author has posted in generated by the following code:

```
<?php
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug
    FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
    WHERE 1=1 AND (
        posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
        posts.post_author = $curauth->ID AND
        tax.taxonomy = 'category' )
    ORDER BY terms.name ASC
");
$x = 0;
?>
<ul class="category-list">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) : ?>
    <?php if( $x%2 ){ ?>
    <li class="odd">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
    <?php } ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php $x++; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

What I'm after doing is to add the number of posts within each category in the foreach loop, next to the category in parentheses.

Any idea how would I go about doing so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can try a much less elegant but a working solution which is to get all of the users posts and count their categories:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'author' => $curauth->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
    );
if ($query->have_posts()){
    $u_cats = array();
    while ($query->have_posts()){
        $query->the_post();
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category');
        foreach ($terms as $term){
            if (is_array($u_cats[$term->term_id])){
                $u_cats[$term->term_id]['count'] = $u_cats[$term->term_id]['count'] +1;
            }else{
                $u_cats[$term->term_id]['count'] = 1;
                $u_cats[$term->term_id]['name'] = $term->name;
                $u_cats[$term->term_id]['ID'] = $term->term_id ;
            }
        }
    }
    //Now $u_cats is an array of categories each with name, ID and author post count for that category
    $x = 0;
?>
<ul class="category-list">
    <?php foreach($u_cats as $category) : 
     if( $x%2 ){ ?>
    <li class="odd">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li>
    <?php } ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category['ID'] ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category['name'];?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>(<?php echo $category['count']; ?>)
    </li>
    <?php $x++; endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)?

```
wp_list_categories( 'show_count=1' );
```

Comment: Hi, the reason I didn't use wp_list_categories() is I'm just after the categories the author has posted in. (Unless there's some way of passing the author as an argument to that function?)

Comment: I see, my bad. No, but you could get all post IDs for the author and then use `update_object_term_cache`, but the `count` field will still be for all posts, not just the current author's.